# weak convergence of a pair of random elements

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Consider two sequences $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ of random elements in some nice (e.g. Polish) space s.t. $X_n\Rightarrow X$ and $Y_n\Rightarrow Y$ ("$\Rightarrow$" denotes weak convergence). Then we know that in general $(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow(X,Y)$ doesn't hold. However, if for instance $Y=c$ is deterministic, then $(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow(X,c)$ is true. One can find this in every basic book on proba theory.

Now are there any more interesting conditions apart from the one I gave where one still gets weak convergence of the pair $(X_n,Y_n)$? Like $(X_n,Y_n)$ independent, or somehow mixing. Or $X_n$ and $Y_n$ independent/mixing. Are there some results out there? The weaker the condition, the better ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f,g$ be two positive Borelian functions.

If $X_n ,Y_n$ are independent and $X,Y$ as well, then
$$
E[f(X_n) g(Y_n)] = E[f(X_n)] E[g(Y_n)] \to E[f(X)] E[g(Y)] = E[f(X) g(Y)]
$$
hence $(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow(X,Y)$.

Comment: Shouldn't one prove $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n,Y_n)]\to\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)]$ for a bounded continuous function $f:(E,E)\to\mathbb{R}$, where $E$ denotes the underlying space?

Comment: this is enough, because of the monotone classes theorem.

Comment: ok, give me some time to digest your statement :)